# Error when using ScriptManager to close current window and open another one

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a problem when executing below line of code, I want to show success message and then closing the current window and open another one.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
"alertMessage", "alert(' Progress Has Been Finished '), 
window.close(), window.open('ReqProgDetail.aspx?v=0&codLic="+ 
Convert.ToInt32(_idlicense) + "#section1') ", true);
```

My HiddenField :

```
HiddenField _idlicense = (HiddenField)dv.FindControl("hid_id_license");
```

and this is my exception message :

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' to type 
'System.IConvertible'. 
at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
```

Comment: "_idlicense" is hidden field?

Comment: can you attach your hidden field in your post

Comment: use (int)_idlicense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're trying to convert `HiddenField` object into int, so you have to retrieve value in `HiddenField` object first before converting it to `int`.

try changing part of your code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(_idlicense)
```

into :

```
Convert.ToInt32(_idlicense.Value)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I forget about that